# Expiring inactive connections on RabbitMQ broker

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm running into the connection limit on my RabbitMQ broker

A method for raising the number of allowed connections is discussed in this thread:
http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-May/013033.html

> On Mon, May 30, 2011 at 06:19:47PM +0530, Dhinesh Kumar wrote:
>
> I am trying to find the maximum number of amqp connections i can establish
> with a RabbitMQ broker running on Ubuntu.
> I tried both Java and erlang client to create connections but i could not
> succeed more than 829 connections.
>
> I like to know how can i increase the number ??

And a solution is offered:

> On Mon, May 30, 2011 at 8:14AM, Matthew Sackman wrote:
>
> You're likely hitting the ulimit. Edit /etc/security/limits.conf and
> allow the rabbitmq user to have a much higher "nofile" setting. Rabbit
> will log on start up how many sockets it's permitting, so once the
> change has taken effect and you've restarted rabbit, you should find
> log entries to demonstrate it's working.
>
> Matthew

While I can raise this limit, I'd rather close unused connections. Is there a method for expiring connections which have not been used in a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by turning on heartbeats:

https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/pika/heartbeat.py

```py
params = ConnectionParameters(host='127.0.0.1', heartbeat=True)
connection = BlockingConnection(params)
```

That way, if a connection is interrupted, the server handles shutting it down.